# Social security and bank account numbers in plain text in web app

Tags: privacy, audit

I am in an "argument" with my company about them showing each and every employees social security and full banking routing / account number in plain text on a leading hosted HR Management software application.  They have the ability to hide it, like every other application I have ever seen, but they refuse to for their convenience.  They cite things like it is hosted in the same server farm as the CIA.

I am not too concerned with security in the backend systems, just the fact that they present the data to a user logging into the system in the front end of the application in plain text (though encrypted).  I know it is bad practice to do this, but I can't get them to budge.

I believe that the application has 2 factor authentication set up for reports and more data vulnerable functions.  The application does use RSA 2048 / sha256RSA.

I have brought up the Sony, White House, Anthem, and OPM hacks, but they still shrugged it off.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to convince them to turn on masking of these fields (XXX-XX-1234)?

Are there any laws, lawsuits or other kinds of guidance that I could cite to help push the securing of this information (like PCI DSS compliance)?

I guess the real question should be:
How do I elegantly explain this to "people who do not understand the actual risk"?  (this was run by the "risk manager" as well)

Asked for legal ramifications [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/14916/social-security-and-bank-account-numbers-in-plain-text-in-web-app)

Comment: Law related questions should be asked in the law stackexchange

Comment: @Limit True. On the other hand, PCI DSS compliance is on-topic here.

Comment: @Limit, not a legal question.  It is meant to be an information security question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! As it is, this question may need some work to be on-topic. It is currently very broad and somewhat opinion-based (basically "how can I convince management?"). If you can point at specific standards that your company follows, then you could ask if the practice violates these. Ideally, show that you have tried to solve it for yourself - "I found point so-and-so in the standards documents, is the practice in violation of that point?"

Comment: @LuckyLindy if you want to know about what laws you can site to make your case, I honestly believe that you'll get better help in the law stackexchange.

Comment: To be clear, you're describing _your_ SSN and _your_ bank account info being made available to you, your boss, and probably HR and financial departments?  Not to unrelated parties like coworkers?  (And this is not a PCI-DSS issue, there's no card data involved, bank accounts are not credit cards).

Comment: "bank accounts are not credit cards" tell that to Jeremy Clarkson "The Top Gear host revealed his account numbers after rubbishing the furore over the loss of 25 million people's personal details on two computer discs.

He wanted to prove the story was a fuss about nothing.

But Clarkson admitted he was "wrong" after he discovered a reader had used the details to create a £500 direct debit to the charity Diabetes UK." http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/entertainment/7174760.stm

Comment: PCI DSS is an industry standard that only governs payment cards, and is enforced only by contractual agreement between payment providers, payment processors, and merchants. PCI DSS is not the law, nor is it a watchdog with any enforcement ability. It does not govern SSNs or bank account numbers. However, there may be government departments who *do* investigate and enforce security standards in relation to SSNs and bank details; in the UK we have the Information Commissioner's Office (ICO) which enforces the Data Protection Act 1998 via imposed fines and restrictions.

Comment: @TopherBrink astonishingly, direct debit is not a credit card charge, and bank account numbers are not credit cards and not subject to PCI.  These terms have actual, discrete meanings.

Comment: Thank you @gowenfawr, I had misinterpreted what you had said, I was just saying that just as much care should be taken with bank details as card details.

Comment: Thanks for comments.  This is not a PCI issue as there are no credit cards involved.  I don't think it is technically a legal issue as I do not know of any laws about showing / storing SSN and bank account numbers in plain text.  This is the problem.  They don't see the need to protect it.  How do I give them irrefutable evidence to do it?
@S.L.Barth, I'll try to rephrase ...

Comment: @S.L.Barth, I know the answers of how someone can compromise the data on a public network connection, how they can hack an account, etc.  I assume they know what could happen if someone has all of your information: identity theft, debit out of your account, etc.  I am not skilled at the art of persuasion, and thought that someone here might be better equipped at convincing them.

Comment: @Limit asked in Law as well as I think they will have some good feedback as we.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 things here, them storing the data in a readable format and them showing you. They do need the data to be in a readable (by the program) format because it is needed to send people money and for tax reasons or to put on wage slips.

They should however not show you sensitive information that you don't need to see. If you wanted to you could use all that information for malicious activities. It is their responsibility to reduce the attack vectors without reducing functionality, giving you this info is making an unnecessary attack vector for little or no functionality.

The fact that the server farm is the same as the CIA means nothing. Its like saying that you live next to a police station so you wont get robbed. Additionally they should not know that they are in the same farm as the CIA because that now tells you one place the CIA have servers and that is info the CIA dont want anyone to know due to possible attacks against them. Lastly I wouldn't trust any government bodies with my data, most of the data breaches from whistle blowers are of data that the whistle blower should not have access to (Edward Snowden, Chelsea Manning, Harold Martin)

Comment: "They should however not show you sensitive information that you don't need to see"

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.
This is what I am trying to convince them of.  I can't make a valid point other than it is not good practice.  What specifically makes it "their responsibility to reduce the attack vectors"?  I am looking for specific reasons and examples. Without these, I cannot convince them.
"live next to a police station so you wont get robbed" :-)

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your point correctly, you are worried with the fact that **your** information is presented to **you** when **you** log in?

If so this is a matter of arguably "bad practices" (except if there is a law which forces a service provider to hide personal data to the owner of the data). I just checked on amazon.com and my bank account: both show me a partial number - you could use such references.

There is however no systems / applicative security involved here: if the data is stored appropriately (= securely enough with the constraints of the intended usage) then the fact that one hides some information is to prevent its reuse by people other than the owner of the data (someone looking over your shoulder for instance).

Therefore your only way is to explain that the data presented in plain sight may be overlooked by someone else, with possible (though complicated to prove) implications for the service provider.

Unfortunately, the dialogue about "data stored in the same place as CIA" does not apply here, which means that this discussion is held between people who do not understand the actual risk (again, if I correctly got what you are asking).

Comment: I am not really concerned about my data, more of others in the large company that are not aware of safe computing practices.  But yes, I am worried that the information is presented to me without masking.
Yes: "people who do not understand the actual risk"